# Web service with Database connection & methods

Tags: database, web-services, sql-server-2008, apache-axis

I have already created web service with android client

web service have add method and android client send paramaters and get result.

But now, I need database connection on my web service in order to android client needs insert,update and delete functionality on database.

I used java axis2 on web service.

What is best way to implement  database connection on web service?

Can i do like normal java class that connect database with jdbc or do i need spring framework that integrated with Hibernate and Axis2?

Is there a tutorial or example applications for that ?

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Stack Overflow is not generally very welcoming to questions like "What is the best way to do X?" since it's a completely subjective matter and depends entirely on the situation. Also, you should edit your question to contain only the relevant parts: I, for one, fail to see what the Android client has to do with your web server database implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a normal Java class that connects to the database with JDBC. Spring Framework is not needed, unless you are creating lots of classes that access the database, at which point Spring will probably make it easier for you to manage everything. Oracle kindly provides you with an extensive [JDBC Basics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/index.html) tutorial that you should read.